# Converting PySpark dataframe to the training data format required for LinearRegression?

Tags: pyspark

The format in the [PySpark docs/examples](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html#generalized-linear-regression) for Linear Regression is:

`print training`

> DataFrame[label: double, features: vector]

My current Spark DataFrame is:

`print df`

> DataFrame[_c0: String, col1: double, col2: double, col3: double, ... colN: double]

How can I use my DataFrame with PySparks Linear Regression module?

Comment: you should probably use 

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=vector#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

Comment: @EzerK please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some ML frameworks such as sklearn use one column as target and many columns as features, spark ML requires a target column and a features column containing a vector.

In order to get from the many columns to a single vector containing column there is a designated saprk function called  VectorAssembler.

See the details in the docs: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=vector#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler